# Regexp lookbehind javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regexp that matches correctly everything I need (all the email addresses NOT inside a link):

```
/((?<!mailto:|=|[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.‌​-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64}(?![a-zA-Z]|<\/[aA]>))/
```

Unfortunately, since javascript does not support lookbehind, it does not work on my web app.
Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, you have to look behind to know there is no starting link tag `<a>` before the email address.

You can try:

1. match each email address, and then verify that the email address is not inside a link programmatically

or

1. use AJAX send the data to your server, and get your server to do the Regex.